# Variational calculus with pointwise constraint involving derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, optimization

I am looking for the Euler-Langrange equations for the following problem:

---

Find the extremal points of the functional
$$ \mathcal{F}(u)=\int_\Omega F(x,u(x),D(u)(x)) dx $$
under the the pointwise constraint $G(D(u))=0$.
Here, $u:\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ and $F:(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^{m\times n})\to\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore $D(u)$ denotes the Jacobian of $u$.

---

Motivation:
I am looking for a trajectory $u(t,p)=(x(t,p),y(t,p))$ under the constraint $|u_p|=1$.

Known related results: I know that for pointwise constraints of the form $G(u)=0$, the above can be achieved by introducing Langrange multipliers and simply finding the extremal points of $F(x,u(x),D(u)(x))+\Lambda(x)\cdot G(u(x))$, however I am unsure if the results can be extended to the case involving the derivatives of $u$.

I would appreciate your help or references to e.g. a textbook. Thank you very much in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Observe that after a Taylor expansion, and choosing $v(x)\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$,
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\left(\int_{\Omega}\Lambda(x)G(D(u(x)+\varepsilon v(x))dx\int_{\Omega}\Lambda(x)G(D(u(x))dx\right)
=-\int _{\Omega}D(\lambda(x)u(x))G'(D(u(x)))v(x)dx
$$
means
$$\frac{\delta\mathcal{F}}{\delta u}=\mathrm{Usual\ stuff}-D(\Lambda(x)u(x))G'(D(u(x)).
$$

Comment: But is it so straightforward that $F+\Lambda G$ is indeed the correct functional in this case?

Comment: Yes. And this would still work if G depended on any derivative of u (as long as everything is smooth enough). Why do you doubt it?

Comment: I followed the proof for this kind of constraint ($G(u)$) and the extension to $G(u,D(u))$ was not obvious at all.